# Web application UTF-8 encoding issue on Debian

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, web-applications, debian, tomcat7

I have an issue with a web application's form encoding. The encoding is supposed to be utf-8 throughout. The problem: if the input into a web app's form contains cyrillic or german characters e.g üäö the input is transformed to Ã¼Ã¤Ã¶. Every possible filter in spring config and tomcat is set to utf-8. The encoding works correctly if I run the web app on tomcat inside eclipse or deploy it as WAR file on a windows machine with tomcat7. It doesen't work on a remote Debian machine with tomcat configured exactly as on the windows machine. Locales on debian are set to "DE.UTF8" also appended "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to catalina.sh but nothing works.
My encoding settings insede the web app:
Spring (only Java config is used) :

```
        @Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
{
    FilterRegistration charEncodingfilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("CharacterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    charEncodingfilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
}
```

JSPs

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Tomcat web.xml:

```
        <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        </filter>
```

Whats really odd is that GET requests work flawlessly everywhere but POST requests are broken only when web app is deployed on the remote Debian server. Any idea what else could influence the encoding?

Comment: is the DB involved? Its yet another possible thing to check, if you're storing the data in DB the connection should be set to UTF8 as well. For mysql you would append a characterEncoding=UTF-8 to the connections string.

Comment: Yes, the web app is connected to a MySQL db via Tomcat dbcp. Connection is already specified as utf-8. Wierd thing is that it works correctly on my local Windows machine but not on the remote Debian server.